# Unmarshalling NullPointerException

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have had some difficulty finding out why I am getting a NullPointerException whilst trying to unmarshal a file. Basically, when I load a saved project into my app I am trying to unmarshal the file first so that any additions the user makes won't write over the file and are instead added to it. The null exception occurs on in the unmarshalling method which I've marked with a comment. This happens even though my test file contains 6 entries of `<savedPosition>`.

My Action listener to call my method:

```
public class Action implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        GetFilePath op = new GetFilePath();
        loadProjectUrl = op.openProjectUrl();
        ArrayList<SavedPosition> oldPos = new ArrayList<SavedPosition>();
        oldPos = FileUnmarshaller.main(loadProjectUrl);
    }

};
```

My unmarshalling method:

```
public class FileUnmarshaller{

public static ArrayList<SavedPosition> main(String url) {

    ArrayList<SavedPosition> posList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SavedPositions.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        SavedPositions savedPositions = (SavedPositions) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(url));
        ArrayList<SavedPosition> list = savedPositions.getPositionList();

        //error occurs here

        SavedPosition savePos : list
        for (SavedPosition savePos : list){
            savePos.getPosition1();
            savePos.getPosition2();
            savePos.getVideo1Url();
            savePos.getVideo2Url();

            posList.add(savePos);

            SavedPositions savedPos = new SavedPositions();
            savedPos.setSavedPositions(posList);

        } 

        return posList;

    } 

    catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileUnmarshaller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileUnmarshaller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return posList;

    }
}
```

My saved positions XML

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "savedPosition")
public class SavedPosition {

    long position1;
    long position2;
    String video1Url;
    String video2Url;

    public String getVideo1Url() {
        return video1Url;
    }

    public void setVideo1Url(String video1Url) {
        this.video1Url = video1Url;
    }

    public String getVideo2Url() {
        return video2Url;
    }

    public void setVideo2Url(String video2Url) {
        this.video2Url = video2Url;
    }

    public long getPosition1() {
        return position1;
    }

    public void setPosition1(long position1) {
        this.position1 = position1;
    }


    public long getPosition2() {
        return position2;
    }


    public void setPosition2(long position2) {
        this.position2 = position2;

    }
```

My Saved Position XML

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "doubleviewer")
    public class SavedPositions {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "savedPositions")

     //set name of entities
     @XmlElement(name = "savedPosition")
     static ArrayList<SavedPosition> savedList;

    public void setSavedPositions(ArrayList<SavedPosition> savedList) {
        this.savedList = savedList;
    }

    public ArrayList<SavedPosition> getPositionList() {
        return savedList;
    }

    public static void reset(){

        savedList.clear();

    }

}
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at doubleviewer.FileUnmarshaller.main(FileUnmarshaller.java:36)
at doubleviewer.DoubleViewer$Action.actionPerformed(DoubleViewer.java:1084)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

XML Structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doubleviewer>
    <savedPositions>
        <savedPosition>
            <position1>551</position1>
            <position2>551</position2>
            <video1Url>file:///C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/Untitled.avi</video1Url>
            <video2Url>file:///C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/Untitled.avi</video2Url>
        </savedPosition>
        <savedPosition>
            <position1>5478</position1>
            <position2>5478</position2>
            <video1Url>file:///C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/Untitled.avi</video1Url>
            <video2Url>file:///C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/Untitled.avi</video2Url>
        </savedPosition>
    </savedPositions>
</doubleviewer>
```

Comment: Post your XML please.

Comment: @lexicore, I added my XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was that my SavedPositions class was using a static value for the `ArrayList<SavedPosition> savedList;` Once I changed this the code was fixed.